# Refactoring PHP script for adding new SELECT query for insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a working PHP script that currently runs SQL queries to pull data from different tables in INSERT/UPDATE one single table.
It's working fine but I now need to add a new select query to it and after a bit of refactoring I'm only needing to use one sql server connection now which helps me in terms of simplicity. However, I'm still having a hard time figuring out the best way to do what I need to do.

Below, I have `$data` which is my existing/working SELECT query and `$stmt` which is my existing/working INSERT. In the middle, howerver, is `$data3` which is my new SELECT that I haven't gotten working for the INSERT yet.

The `$data3` query gets the correct results, but since it's taking place on the same connection as `$data`, I'm not sure the best way to use it in the existing INSERT.

My other issue is that I need to insert them based on user ID. There is a column in the table which I'm inserting into (ambition_totals) called `ext_id`. So I need to insert on the basis that `c.user` from `$data3` = `ambition_totals.ext_id`. So basically `/////INSERT INTO ambition_totals where c.user = ext_id`.

How can I change the syntax of my new query and the insert so that I can use the one INSERT for all the values in both statements? And what constraint would I need to add to the insert so that the `$data3` values are inserted based on the user ID equivalenct?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    //This is the existing query, it works perfectly and the values from it are successfully being inserted by $stmt below

    $data = mysqli_query($conn2,
        "SELECT distinct
          case
          when callingpartyno       in  (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
          then callingpartyno
          when finallycalledpartyno in  (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
          then finallycalledpartyno
          end as extension
            , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
            , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
            , sum( case when(legtype1 = 1 and duration > 60) then 1 else 0 end) as credit_for_outbound
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +      -- outbound calls
              sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
            , round((sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1))/(sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +     -- outbound calls
              sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))) * 100,2) as percent_answered
            , now() as time_of_report
            , curdate() as date_of_report
        FROM
            cdrdb.session a
            join cdrdb.callsummary b
            on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
            where
            date(a.ts) >= curdate()
            and (
            callingpartyno in  (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
            or  finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
            )
            group by
            extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));

    //This is the new Select query, which is selecting 2 new values from a different shcema but on the same server/connection

    $data3 = mysqli_query($conn2,
        "SELECT 
          COUNT(*) AS Number_of_recorded_events,
          ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  AS Percentage_up_to_date
        FROM jfi_dealers.contact_events c
            JOIN jackson_id.users u
            ON c.user = u.id
            JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers d
            ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
            LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
              SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
              FROM jackson_id.attr_list AS al
              JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
              WHERE al.attr_id = 14
              GROUP BY user_id) AS al
            ON al.user_id = c.user
            -- WHERE c.created_at >= CURDATE()
        GROUP BY UserID")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));


    //This is the main INSERT, which currently inserts everything from $data but I need to modify to include $data3 as well

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2,
        "INSERT into ambition.ambition_totals
      (extension,
      total_talk_time_seconds,
      total_talk_time_minutes,
      total_outbound,
      credit_for_outbound,
      total_inbound,
      missed_calls,
      total_calls,
      percent_answered,
      date_of_report,
          time_of_report,
      dealers_contacted,
      percent_up_to_date)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON duplicate key
update
      total_talk_time_seconds = values(total_talk_time_seconds),
      total_talk_time_minutes = values(total_talk_time_minutes),
      total_inbound = values(total_inbound),
      total_outbound = values(total_outbound),
      credit_for_outbound = values(credit_for_outbound),
      missed_calls = values(missed_calls),
      total_calls = values(total_calls),
      percent_answered = values(percent_answered),
      time_of_report = NOW(),
      dealers_contacted = values(dealers_contacted),
      percent_up_to_date = values(percent_up_to_date)) or die(mysqli_error( 
      $conn2));
```

Comment: Sorry, basically the table being inserted into has columns for all the data in both queries. The first query is existing and joins different tables than the 2nd query. So between the 2 queries, I want to insert all 15 values into the table. I'll work on getting the data together for an example

Comment: In other words, the 2 queries return everything I need for the insert statement. I need to take those 15 values and insert into the 15 columns in ambition_totals

Comment: Got it: They would map to dealers_contacted and percent_up_to_date

Comment: Apologies, I misread something when I edited earlier. It is correct now though: 11 values from the first query and 2 values from the 2nd for 13 total.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to apply multi-query syntax to this so that it properly inserts

Comment: Makes more sense but one thing: *There is a column in the table which I'm inserting into (ambition_totals) called ext_id*... I see no *ext_id* in append query.

Comment: It's in the table ambition_totals, but I'm not inserting it here. I'ts something that's updated elsewhere. I just need to equate that value with c.user upon this insert, if that makes sense

Comment: First, let's delete previous comments as you resolved them with edit. Second, how does your `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE...` work if you do not append the primary key? From what I see, this query should not ever run the `UPDATE` portion.

Comment: How are the two queries related? I do not see a user level id in first query? I do have an answer in the works.

Comment: There is another query that updates based on the extension which equates to an id in another database. In this script though, the 2nd query is inserting based on contact_events.user being equal to ambition_totals.ext_id